# What is the equivalent Java collection to a Swift array?

Tags: java, arrays, swift

I've noticed Java has a lot of collection types and I am unsure which one to use. I come from a Swift programming background. What is the closest or equivalent Java collection to a Swift array? From my research, ArrayList, seems to be the closest. I just want to confirm this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `List` interface in Java does expose functionalities similar to the Swift Array struct.

Java provides several implementations of `List`:

1. [AbstractList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html)
2. [AbstractSequentialList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html)
3. [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
4. [AttributeList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/AttributeList.html)
5. [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)
6. [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
7. [RoleList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/relation/RoleList.html)
8. [RoleUnresolvedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/relation/RoleUnresolvedList.html)
9. [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)
10. [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Each one is particularly optimized for some kind of task so you should pick the one that better fits your needs.

Finally yes, `ArrayList` is probably the most commonly used: I also often used that before switching to Swift.

### Class vs Struct

Please keep in mind that the previous list is about Java **classes** while the Swift Array is a **struct**. There are important differences (reference type vs value type) about how these 2 types behave.

E.g. in Swift when you assign an array to a different variable you are actually creating a copy of it

```
let fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi"]
var otherFruits = fruits
otherFruits.removeFirst()

print(fruits) // ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi"]
print(otherFruits) // ["Orange", "Kiwi"]
```

While in Java writing

```
List<String> fruits = ...
List<String> otherFruits = fruits
```

you just create another reference to the **same** array.
 So in this scenario the changes you make to `fruits` will be visible in `otherFruits` (and viceversa).